# How to Create view with 10% of record of a table in hive?

Tags: sql, hive, hql, hiveql

I wanted to create a view on top of my hive table but the view should contain
only 10 % of total records. `Count(*)/10`

How can I do it with `ROWNUM()` or `RANK` function.
it will be very helpful if the data would be random.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an approximate 10% sample is good enough, just include:

```
create view v_t
    select t.*
    from t
    where rand() < 0.1;
```

For a large table, this should be quite close to exactly 10%.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use ntile window function as below:

```
create view v_t
    select * from 
    (select *, ntile(10) over(order by rand()) as percentile from tablename) as A 
    where percentile=1
```

I have tested a similar query in Postgres. [Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=94eded534a34ca53e5dd61744ea3aae0)